# Input string was not in a correct format Error Filling a Datatable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ado.net, runtime-error, npgsql

I have a table which is all VarChar() fields.

I fill the dataset with the following SQL (using vb.net):

```
Select * From archive_naerns90_2006_q3.NAERNS90_Calls Where siteid = 'NAERNS90-02-627303'
```

I get this error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <02-627303> in agencyid Column.  Expected type is Double.
```

When I run this query from PgAdmin it works fine. I am running this same bit of code on dozens of other tables with no problems.

The value 02-627303 referenced in the error is the value in the agencyid column for that record, but there are no Double fields in the table. Full disclosure - there were two, but I changed them from Double to VarChar and neither were the agencyid coplumn.

The other kicker is this only happens on some records in that table.

I am guessing I have some corrupt table. I copied the table, but the copy has the same problem. And Since it works in PgAdmin but not from my code it also may have something to do with npgsql.

Edit: I was asked to add the code around the problem area as this looked like an Insert error. I am not doing any Inserts at all in this function.

```
SQL = "Select * From " & MlocRow("currentdb") & "." & SubTablesArr(Y) & " Where siteid = '" & DataRow("siteid") & "'"
Adapter.SelectCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(SQL, MLConnect)
Adapter.Fill(subDT)
```

My ConnectionString is:

```
"HOST=192.168.0.133;DATABASE=masterlists;USER ID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword"
```

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Probably you should show us the code around that query. The message talks about an INSERT but you show code for a SELECT. A bug of this magnitude in the underlying provider is really improbable. Something in your code triggers this error.

Comment: Also, that's not a PostgreSQL error message, so it's not surprising you can't reproduce it with PgAdmin.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can type cast that col to `varchar()` explicitly...